# How to register JS object via Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm new on Node.js and Electron.

I already developed a Web View Application via CefSharp.WinForm.

When I used CefSharp, I added `window.AppViewport` object like this.

```
chromeBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("AppViewport", new AppViewport(this));
```

And in web page, I used the `AppViewport` like this.

```
if(window.AppViewport !== undefined){
    window.AppViewport.setDepth(widthDepthLevel);
}
```

However, I couldn't find `registerAsyncJsObject` or `registerJjObject` in electron.

How can I add the javascript object handler in electron like C# appllication?
Is there anything equivalent with that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `global` object on your `Main` process,

```
global.yourSharedObj = {some_prop: true};
```

and with Electron's Remote API, you can access that object in `Renderer` with something like this:

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;     
console.log(remote.getGlobal('yourSharedObj').some_prop);
```

Remote API Docs:
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md